# Dynamic and variable databases using spring boot

Tags: sql, spring-boot

i'am working on a web application using spring boot. the problem is i have to use a multiple and variable databases. So please i need you to help me and give me ways or researchs to work with dynamic databases.
Thank you.

I didn't try anything because i don't have idea about it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.